A question regarding quasiperiodic and limit-periodic potentials
I am looking for specific references regarding the fact that there are quasiperiodic and, also, limit-periodic potentials $q(x)$ such that
the $L^2(\mathbb{R})$-spectrum $\sigma(H)$ of the operator
\begin{equation*}
Hu = -\dfrac{d^2u}{dx^2} + q(x) u
\end{equation*}
is a closed interval, i.e. $\sigma(H) = [\lambda_0, \infty)$.
